# Any "out of band" hashes in MD* or SHA-*?

Tags: performance, hash, md5, sha

Do any of the common hash algorithms define an "out of band" hash code, i.e. one that is guaranteed to never be the result of the algorithm?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's not about cryptography.  It's about hash functions.

Comment: Those are *cryptographic* hash functions, and there is no programming involved in your question.

Comment: You're basically saying that calculus is not [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) because it's used in other fields as well.

Comment: It is very likely that every possible hash value output is realized for some input, since the input space is absolutely enormous compared to the output and the nature of cryptographic hash function makes any "holes" unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the MD* or SHA-* family of algorithms has an out of band hash value.

If you wish to implement this yourself, you can use the following logic:

- select a random hash value to be the out of band value.
- compute the hash.
- if the hash value (improbably) turns out to be the out of band hash value, assign another hash value.

In pseudocode:

```
OutOfBandHash = 0xdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
h = hash(stuff)
if h = OutOfBandHash
    h = OutOfBandHash + 1
```

Comment: Good, instead of moving the question, provide an incorrect anwer. -1.

Comment: I'm puzzled, you seem to know the answer but refuse to share it. It's a strange attitude! (and presumably you don't know much about H. Ross Perot)

Comment: I'm not refusing to share it, *if* it is asked at the right forum, which I helpfully pointed you to. I'm not going to start answering questions here if they are off topic to begin with. You'll get much better answers at crypto. I know about Ross Perrot unfortunately but I don't get the reference.

Comment: Looking at the RFCs I don't see any reservation of an out of band value, or any way to predict a value that will never be obtained.  If you know otherwise feel free to contribute!  I appreciate your enthusiasm for cryptography, but you should understand that hashing is used in many other fields as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what hashing the selected 'out of band' value is supposed to accomplish? That will identify fixed points (if you find one, congratulations, please share it), but doesn't say anything about what other preimages might lead to it.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. You say `h=hash()` but don't give an argument to hash(). So what is h the hash of?

Comment: @GregS, sorry, I have added the context of h=hash(stuff) to make it clearer.

Comment: @NickJohnson I have a computationally expensive data structure to compare, so I'd like to traverse a graph of hash values.  Being able to represent a "has not been hashed" data structure with an integral value instead of a struct will make my code cleaner and a bit faster.  I don't think this will allow me to identify any fixed points but if I do I'll send it along!

Comment: @MarkHarrison I understand why you want the OOB hash value. What I don't understand is how hashing it and comparing it to itself helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no out of band hash values for MD5, SHA-1 or one of the SHA-2 candidates. The output of cryptograhic hashes is guaranteed to be indistinguishable from random. That said, if you generate a value of the same size as e.g. SHA-256 (32 bytes) *that is not already a known hash*, then you are guaranteed that nobody else will generate the same value. This could even be 32 bytes set to all zeros. There are endless messages that will generate the hash value you chose, the point is that it is impossible to find one.

If anybody would be able to generate a hash that has the same value then they would be able to generate a collision. If a collision can be generated then the cryptographic hash is considered broken. MD5 does have collisions and **is** considered broken. For SHA-1 there have been no collisions yet, but the amount of work required to generate one is lower than expected for a hash with 160 bit output, and possibly already inside reach. Neither MD5 or SHA1 is *currently* so broken that you would be able to generate any random hash value, but attacks only get better, not worse.

So in the end you would be best off choosing SHA-256 or SHA-512 for this particular purpose. Note that although you can use just X leftmost bytes of the output, you should use at least 160 bits or so to be reasonably sure that there is no collision - for non-broken hash algorithms the output size determines the chance of collisions.